# UseEffect creates a loop + does not pass parameters to UrlParams

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Trying to create a switch to filter through on-site/remote job posts using UseEffect but it creates an infinite loop and I can't figure out why. (jobCondition, in this case, is UseState hook) + when I try to pass params in `conditions:` ${condition}`,` it does not work. Can somebody help explain to me what am I doing wrong in these 2 cases? Thanks!

```
const getJobsLocation = async () => {
    const queryParams = { page: 1, limit: 10 };
    const response = await getJobs(queryParams);
    if (!response) {
      return;
    }
    const searchResults = [];
    response.data.nodes.forEach((loc) => {
      searchResults.push({ title: loc.jobLocation });
    });
    getJobsLocation(searchResults);
    console.log(searchResults);
  };
  useEffect(() => {
    let condition = getJobsLocation();
    switch (jobCondition) {
      case 'On-site': condition.filter((con) => con.jobLocation === 'in_person');
        break;
      case 'Remote': condition.filter((con) => con.jobLocation === 'remote');
        break;
      case 'Hybrid': condition.filter((con) => con.jobLocation === 'hybrid');
        break;
      default:
        condition = null;
    }[condition];
    if (condition != null) {
      const params = new URLSearchParams({
        jobs: jobFilter || null,
        location: locationFilter || null,
        since: datePosted || null,
        conditions: `${condition}`,
      });
      history.push({ pathname: '/', search: `${params.toString()}` });
      return;
    }
    const params = new URLSearchParams({
      jobs: jobFilter || null,
      location: locationFilter || null,
      since: null,
      conditions: null,
    });
    history.push({ pathname: '/', search: `${params.toString()}` });
  }, [jobCondition]);
```

Answer (score 0):

please note that `let condition = getJobsLocation();` this function is an `async` function that needs to be `await`'ed on.. and it actually returns nothing so even after you `await` it it will be the `condition` variable will be `undefined`